# Uwsgi procces blocks request

Tags: python, django, http, nginx, uwsgi

While testing nginx server with uwsgi and django I am having problem with uwsgi process. I am sending two posts, which are taking a lot of time. Meanwhile server processing I am sending get request from webrowser and I must wait till this two post finished. I am starting uwsgi with this command:

```
cd /home/pi/cukierek && uwsgi -
-max-requests=5000 
--socket /tmp/cukierek.sock 
--module config.wsgi  
--master-fifo /tmp/cukierek.fifo 
--chmod-socket=777 --processes 2 
--daemonize /home/pi/cukierek/wsgi.log 
--enable-threads
```

It is possible to get answer from browser while this two post are beeing in progress ? I am using default nginx settings.

Answer (score 0):

You have a uwsgi server configured to spawn 2 processes. Then you run 2 long requests. Those 2 processes are busy with the long requests, so new requests must wait until the long requests finish.

If you want to send new reqeusts to the server while the long requests run, increase the processes to more than 2 (ie --processes 4)

Comment: I think it does. If he increases the processes to 4 he will get an answer from the uwsgi server while the other 2 long processes run.